# load_current_value when there are no properties

Tags: chef-infra

Let's say I have this very simple custom chef resource:

```
property :path, String, name_property: true

action :create_if_missing do
  file "#{new_resource.path}" do
    content ''
  end
end
```

which I use like this in another recipe:

```
touch_touch '/tmp/foo'
```

When I converge this recipe multiple times, I get this on the first run

```
Recipe: foo::default
  * touch_touch[/tmp/foo] action create_if_missing
    * file[/tmp/foo] action create
      - create new file /tmp/foo
      - update content in file /tmp/foo from none to e3b0c4
      (no diff)
```

and this on subsequent runs

```
Recipe: foo::default
  * touch_touch[/tmp/foo] action create_if_missing
    * file[/tmp/foo] action create (up to date)
     (up to date)
```

What do I have to change so that I get something like this instead?

```
Recipe: foo::default
  * touch_touch[/tmp/foo] action create_if_missing (up to date)
```

I believe I have to wrap my action in converge_if_changed like this

```
action :create_if_missing do
  converge_if_changed do
    file "#{new_resource.path}" do
      content ''
    end
  end
end
```

But what do I put in load_current_value? Usually I'd read the current state (e.g. from disk) and populate current_resource with that information. But my resource doesn't have any properties (except the file name).

Comment: A resource property is required for `load_current_value` so that it can be compared during converge. Can you not add something like `content` property (with default value) in your custom resource?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @seshadri_c for your suggestion.

I added a dummy property and fill that in load_current_value:

```
property :file_exists, [true, false], default: true

load_current_value do |new_resource|
  file_exists ::File.exist?(new_resource.path)
end
```

That works. However, this new property allows the user to break the resource. So I'd prefer a solution without it.

Additional answers welcome!